# Facebook Share Button Functionality

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I want to add Facebook share button in my website so that user can share any post ,content of given url.
I want to know how can I get that either user is shared  something or not on Facebook  because I have to store user data in database if user share any post,content of given url from my website.

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=example.org" target="_blank">
  Share on Facebook
</a>
```

Comment: Instead of `sharer.php` why don't you use `Feed Dialog` using which you may do the work you require easily?

Comment: @AnveshSaxena   Can Feed Dialog work without app_id or without Facebook page or app?

Comment: it requires an app Id

Comment: @AnveshSaxena  Is there any other way for it without app_id?.

Comment: Nope, it is necessary for it to work. I think this would be better option than to manipulate over the Facebook's controlled `sharer.php`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution .

code :-

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:fb="https://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
<head>
<title>My Feed Dialog Page</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id='fb-root'></div>
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js'></script> 
<a onclick='postToFeed(); return false;' style="cursor:pointer;"><img src="img/xyz.jpg"></a>
<p id='msg' style="display:none"><?php echo $_REQUEST['id'] ?></p>
<script> 

       FB.init({appId: "your app id", status: true, cookie: true});
        function postToFeed() { 
             var obj = {
                      method: 'feed',
                      //redirect_uri: 'YOUR URL HERE',
                      link: 'https://www.abc.in/',
                      picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
                      name: 'abc',
                      caption: 'User Has Won points ',
                      description: 'Share Test.'
                    };
         function callback(response) {  
               //document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
               var id=$("p").html();
              if(response['post_id']!=null)
              {
                $.ajax({
                    url:'customer.php',
                    data:'fbpoints='+'1'+'&customer_id='+id,
                    dataType:'html',
                    success:function(res){ alert(res);
                     } 
                 });

             }

        }
        FB.ui(obj, callback);
      }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```